# Mapbox: Why isn't my for loop calling in the list of locations to the flyTo function? "...addEventListener is not a function"

Tags: html, list, for-loop, mapbox

I am trying to create multiple flyTo buttons corresponding to different views, using a for loop to run through all views, rather than repeating the function for each view.

I am doing this by populating a list with the button names, so I can call this in to the for loop containing the flyTo function.

Problems occur in this loop, where I get the error "Uncaught TypeError: names[i].addEventListener is not a function".

I have tried calling elements[i].addEventListener... instead, but then get an error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'center' of undefined at HTMLButtonElement."

This error is removed when "center: views[i].center" is replaced with "center: views[0].center", or any specific view - and all buttons fly to this one view.

I think I have everything there for it to work, but something is not right with the method and I'm struggling to solve it. I think there should be only one for loop, which creates a list of button names and links these to the views. Any help would be greatly appreciated - here is a link to my code:

http://jsfiddle.net/bsbdyvrv/2/

```
<div id='map' class="myMap"></div>

<!-- View buttons -->
<div id='console'>
    <button class="location" name='loc 1' id='v1'>View 1</button>
    <button class="location" name='loc 2' id='v2'>View 2</button>
    <button class="location" name='loc 3' id='v3'>View 3</button>
</div>

<script>

// Mapboxgl demo app
'use strict';
var map;
mapboxgl.accessToken = 'pk.eyJ1IjoiYmVuamFtaW4td3lzcyIsImEiOiJVcm5FdEw4In0.S8HRIEq8NqdtFVz2-BwQog';

// init the map
map = new mapboxgl.Map({
    container: 'map',
    style: 'https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-styles/styles/outdoors-v7.json',
    center: [-1.83, -78.183],
    zoom: 5.5,
});

var views = [{
              name: "View 1",
              zoom: 10,
              pitch: 0,
              bearing: 0,
              center: [-0.33,-78.49],
            },
            {
              name: "View 2",
              zoom: 10,
              pitch: 0,
              bearing: 0,
              center: [-1.04,-79.43],
            },
            {
              name: "View 3",
              zoom: 10,
              pitch: 0,
              bearing: 0,
              center: [-2.19,-78.11],
            },

          ];


 // Populate list with button names
  var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('location');
  var names = '';
    for(var i=0; i<elements.length; i++) {
     names += elements[i].name;
    }
  document.write(names);

  // For each button, fly to corresponding view
    for(var i=0; i<elements.length; i++) {
        names[i].addEventListener('click', function () {
        map.flyTo({
            center: views[i].center
            // zoom: app.views[i].zoom,
            // pitch: app.views[i].pitch,
            // bearing: app.views[i].bearing
        });
      });
   };
</script>
```

Comment: I see that you are adding an event listener to a string (names), you can only  add an event to the document or an element.  Just add the event in the first loop elements[i].addEventListerner....

Comment: Thanks for the quick response - this does fix the problem, but I then get an error with 'center' being undefined when the views run through the iteration. This makes me think maybe I don't need the list at all, if I am not referring back to the names string.

Comment: I would use data attributes instead, i will provide an example and add and answer

Answer (score 0):

```js
// Mapboxgl demo app
'use strict';

var map;

mapboxgl.accessToken = 'pk.eyJ1IjoiYmVuamFtaW4td3lzcyIsImEiOiJVcm5FdEw4In0.S8HRIEq8NqdtFVz2-BwQog';

// init the map
map = new mapboxgl.Map({
  container: 'map',
  style: 'https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-styles/styles/outdoors-v7.json',
  center: [-1.83, -78.183],
  zoom: 5.5,
});


// Populate list with button names
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('location');
var names = '';
for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
  names += elements[i].name;
  elements[i].addEventListener('click', function(event) {

    var zoom = parseInt(event.target.dataset.zoom);
    var pitch = parseInt(event.target.dataset.pitch);
    var bearing = parseInt(event.target.dataset.bearing);
    var lat = parseFloat(event.target.dataset.lat);
    var long = parseFloat(event.target.dataset.long);

    map.flyTo({
      center: [long, lat]
      // zoom: app.views[i].zoom,
      // pitch: app.views[i].pitch,
      // bearing: app.views[i].bearing
    });
  });
}
document.write(names);
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

#map {
  height: 61%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v0.8.0/mapbox-gl.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div id='map' class="myMap"></div>

<!-- View buttons -->
<div id='console'>
  <button class="location" name='loc 1' id='v1' data-zoom="10" data-pitch="0" data-bearing="0" data-long="-0.33" data-lat="-78.49">View 1</button>
  <button class="location" name='loc 2' id='v2' data-zoom="10" data-pitch="0" data-bearing="0" data-long="-1.04" data-lat="-79.43">View 2</button>
  <button class="location" name='loc 3' id='v3' data-zoom="10" data-pitch="0" data-bearing="0" data-long="-2.19" data-lat="-78.11">View 3</button>
</div>

<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v0.8.0/mapbox-gl.js"></script>
```